# WP7 - Detect 'Click' event on a MapPolygon

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am developing an app for windows phone 7.

I have an overlay on the standard Map object that contains several MapPolygon objects.

What is the best and/or simplest solution for knowing if the user has tapped one of the polygons?

Comment: I found that I can use the MouseLeftButtonUp event to detect taps on the map and the polygon, however, both events fire when a user taps on a polygon. I also need to know a user taps the map, but not a polygon.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) is probably the easiest way to do it.  Once added to your project use the gesture listener like so:

```
var gestureListener = GestureService.GetGestureListener(poly);
gestureListener.Tap += new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(gestureListener_Tap);
```

Where gestureListener_Tap is the method called.

Comment: In Windows Phone 7.1 "Mango" (The current/latest release of the SDK), the Tap event handler is available on all elements, and the GestureListener is **removed** from the Silverlight Toolkit.

Comment: Ok, since the Mango release isn't out yet for the phone, I want to stay compatible with 7.0 so I can test it on my device. I also want to make it compatible with 7.1, so I don't want to use the GestureListener either. Thanks though.